# Upgrading Rails 2.3.8 app to Rails 3.0.1, cannot call create on any models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to upgrade from 2.3.8 to 3.0.1, but this problem has been plaguing me and preventing further progress for quite some time now. Any attempt to create something from my models (calling Subject.create! from the console, for example) always results in this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for 0:Fixnum
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `block in create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `each'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `detect'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/engines/sql/engine.rb:26:in `create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/algebra/relations/writes.rb:24:in `call'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/session.rb:17:in `create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/arel-1.0.1/lib/arel/algebra/relations/relation.rb:159:in `insert'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:14:in `insert'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:271:in `create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:47:in `create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `block in create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_create_callbacks'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:281:in `create'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:247:in `create_or_update'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:in `block in create_or_update'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_save_callbacks'
... 1 levels...
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:56:in `save!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:in `save!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:242:in `block in save!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:289:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:242:in `save!'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:34:in `create!'
from (irb):1
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'ruby-1.9.2-p0
```

It would appear Arel is not getting a proper relation to work with, but I am lost as to what is causing this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: Can you post your model code for Subject?

Comment: Well Subject is actually a large complicated model, but the problem is happening with every model in the app. Here's a very simple model that has the same problem: DataType < ActiveRecord::Base; def to_s; name; end; end

Comment: and you call Subject.create! without any parameters?

Comment: I am just thinking that maybe you are passing a number as one of the parameters for an association, instead of the whole object.  For example  Subject.create!(:user=>1), when it should be Subject.create!(:user_id=>1) or Subject.create!(:user=>User.find(1))

Comment: No, sorry, I was just using that as a quick example. A more accurate example would be if I tried to call DataType.create!(:name => 'String'). DataType's table has only an id and a name. But really the error occurs regardless of if I pass any parameters. My apologies for not being more clear with my original example.

Comment: no problemo.  Just trying to understand whats going on.  I added some debugging tips in the answer I just posted.  Hopefully that will get you closer to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting some debug statements inside arel.   Edit the engine.rb in the last line of the stack trace.  I think you will have to restart the console (not just reload!) to see the changes in the arel file.

Here is the offending line in engine.rb:

```
attribute = relation.record.detect { |attr, _| attr.name.to_s == relation.primary_key.to_s }
```

Maybe try printing out the attr names and see if anything is passing thru the array detect method.  Or print out the class of the "attr".  The class should be "Arel::Attribute", but obviously a Fixnum is passing in there somehow.

```
attribute = relation.record.detect do |attr, _|
   p attr.class
   p attr.name
   attr.name.to_s == relation.primary_key.to_s
end
```

Just a guess but I am thinking maybe a plugin/gem is interfering with something in your models.  Are you using any dependencies that tie directly into ActiveRecord?

Another good exercise would be to create a blank Rails 3 app (with no gems or plugin dependencies) with one model and see if you get the same errors.  That would rule out something in your development environment.  Then if that works, then maybe you can start removing some of the dependencies one by one from the other app and see if one of them is causing the error.

Comment: Plugin/gem issues do seem very likely now that you mention it. I will mess around with them and see what happens. Don't think any plugins should be tied into ActiveRecord, the only thing I can think of is meta_search, which really just I threw in the app to replace searchlogic, which is broken in Rails 3. Still mysterious because I can query objects like always; it's just updating them that doesn't work. When debugging engine.rb, the hash's key was a Fixnum of 0, and the hash's value was an array containing an "Arel::Attribute" object filled with Arel::Sql and ActiveRecord objects. Thanks!

Comment: Started an new Rails 3 app from scratch and creating objects worked just fine. Added the same plugins/gems and it still worked fine. So I remain stumped for now...

Comment: Using the blank rails3 app and copying over your /app and /config files from your rails 2 project might be the best option here.  I have actually found this to be an easier way to upgrade than trying to convert the existing project using the upgrade plugin.  You could also copy it a few peices at a time and that might help you narrow down what is breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ruby are you using? It should be either `1.8.7` or `1.9.2`. I've had similar inexplicable issues with `1.9.1`.

Comment: While my system has 1.8.7 installed, I'm using 1.9.2-p0 through rvm for this app.

Comment: Are you sure rvm is using the right gems? Run `which ruby` and `which rails` to double check.

Comment: Both seem to be fine, ruby 1.9.2-p0 and rails 3.0.1